# Convert VB6 PictureBox code to VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I am doing project in vb.net which is already done in vb6
I am having text box .I want to apply font (style,color,name,size) to selected text.
I am able to do this ..& want to create bitmap of this textbox text so that i can create matrix of 0,1,2,3 digits if text color is red then 1 digit,green-2,orange-3

Following code is done in vb6 but i am not getting some properties in vb.net like
picture1.point
picture1.print (here picture1 is picture box)
 here Led is array of (digits 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 )
converttodis is functiont that converts each letter into array
  Code is here

```
 Private Sub CmdPreview_Click()
On Error Resume Next
Dim i
Picture1.Cls
lRow = 0
Lcol = 0
ReDim Led(Picture1.TextHeight(TxtMsg.Text), Picture1.TextWidth(TxtMsg.Text))

For i = 1 To Len(TxtMsg.Text)
    TxtMsg.SelStart = i - 1
    TxtMsg.SelLength = 1
    Picture1.Font = TxtMsg.SelFontName
    Picture1.FontSize = TxtMsg.SelFontSize
    Picture1.FontBold = TxtMsg.SelBold
    Picture1.FontItalic = TxtMsg.SelItalic

   If Mid(TxtMsg.Text, i, 1) <> vbCr Then
    Picture1.Print Mid(TxtMsg.Text, i, 1)

    ConvertToDis i, TxtMsg.selcolor

 ElseIf Mid(TxtMsg.Text, i, 2) = vbCrLf Then
    i = i + 1
    lRow = lRow + Picture1.TextHeight(Mid(TxtMsg.Text, i - 2, 1))
    Lcol = 0
   Else

   Picture1.Print Mid(TxtMsg.Text, i, 1)
    ConvertToDis i, TxtMsg.selcolor
  End If
Next

End Sub


Public Function ConvertToDis(ByVal i As Long, ByVal col)

Dim CX, CY, f, f1, F2
Dim lsubrow, Lsubcol As Integer
lsubrow = lRow
Lsubcol = Lcol

For CY = 0 To Picture1.TextHeight(Mid(TxtMsg.Text, i, 1))
For CX = 0 To Picture1.TextWidth(Mid(TxtMsg.Text, i, 1))
  If Picture1.Point(CX, CY) < vbWhite - 4300000 Then

  If col = 255 Then
    LedCol(lsubrow, Lsubcol) = 1
  ElseIf col = 65280 Then
    LedCol(lsubrow, Lsubcol) = 2
  ElseIf col = 33023 Then
    LedCol(lsubrow, Lsubcol) = 3
  Else
    LedCol(lsubrow, Lsubcol) = 0
  End If
DoEvents
  Lsubcol = Lsubcol + 1
Next

 lsubrow = lsubrow + 1
 Lsubcol = Lcol
Next
Picture1.Cls
Lcol = Lcol + Picture1.TextWidth(Mid(TxtMsg.Text, i, 1))
End Function
```

for LONG word output is like this

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000011111000000011111100001111101111000111110000000000
000001110000001111111110000111100111001111111100000000
000001110000001111000110000111100110011110001110000000
000001110000011111000011000111100110111110001000000000
000001110000011010000011000111100110110110000000000000
000001110000011010000011000111110110110111111110000000
000001110000011010000011000110110110110110001111000000
000001110000011010000011000110111110110111111110000000
000001110000011110000011000110011110111100001110000000
000001110000101110000111000110011110011100001110000000
000001110011100111001110000110001110011110001110000000
000011111111110011111100001111001110000111111110000000
000011111111110011111000011111001110000111111111000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Graphics for Visual Basic 6.0 Users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dtfzwyx.aspx):

> In Visual Basic 2008, the `Point` method no longer exists. You can use the [`System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixel(System.Int32,System.Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx) method to retrieve a color value from a bitmap. For forms or controls that do not contain a picture, you can query the [`BackColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.backcolor.aspx) property.
>
> In Visual Basic 2008, the [`DrawString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring.aspx) method is used to display text. The font is determined by a [`Font`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.aspx) object, and the color is determined by a [`Brush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.brush.aspx) object; both are passed as parameters to the `DrawString` method. The `DrawString` method also has `X` and `Y` parameters that determine the starting location for the text. There is also an optional `Format` parameter that takes a [`StringFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataformats.stringformat.aspx) object, allowing you to display text vertically.